# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 's' was corrupted

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2012, stack, runtime-error

I have faced this problem : Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 's' was corrupted in visual studio 12 . I also try this in codeblock but faced same problem . I run my code also in ideone.com it shows runtime error . Help me out ?
my code is :

```
#include<iostream>
  #include<stdio.h>
  #define MAX 50
  using namespace std;
  typedef struct
  {
    long var[20];
    long pos;
  }stack;

   void init_stack(stack *st)
   {
       long i;
       for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
        st->var[i] = -1;
       st->pos = 0;
     return ;
  }

  void push(stack *st, long item)
  {
    if(st->pos == MAX)
    {
        printf("stack overflow \n");
    }
    else
    st->var[st->pos+1] = item;
    st->pos++;
    return ;
  }

  void pop(stack *st)
  {
    //if(empty(st))
    if(st->pos == 0) 
        printf("stack underflow \n");
    else
    st->var[st->pos] = -1;
    st->pos--;
    return ;
  }

  long top(stack *st)
  {
    long temp;
    temp = st->var[st->pos];

    return temp;
    }

bool empty(stack *st)
{
    if(st->pos==0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
{
    stack s;
    long i, n=9, t;
    init_stack(&s);
    printf("STACK PUSH\n");
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        push(&s, i);
        t = top(&s);
        printf("  %ld\n", t);
    }
    printf("STACK POP\n");
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        t = top(&s);
        printf("  %ld\n", t);
        pop(&s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: MAX is 50, and you make var to be an array of 20 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `var` as holding `20` elements, but you iterate `MAX` times over it, `MAX` being defined as `50`. That's probably not what you wanted to do. Try :

`long var[MAX];`